# Why is my Javascript becoming undefined every time I click on my toolbarbutton?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, dom-events

I'm trying to create a simple extension that alerts the mouse click (mouseup) coordinates every time a button is clicked. (A learning attempt)

The extension is working alright and is setup right, except for one glitch.

**My XUL file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="chrome://global/skin/" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css"

href="chrome://mouseclick/skin/mouseclick.css" ?>

<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM
  "chrome://mouseclick/locale/mouseclick.dtd">

<overlay id = "overlay-id" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script type="application/x-javascript"
    src="chrome://mouseclick/content/mouseclick.js" />

    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="mouseclick-button" class="mouseclick-class"
                   label="&button.label;" tooltiptext="&tooltip.text;" 
                   oncommand = "mouseClick.display();"/>
  </toolbarpalette>
  <toolbar id="nav-bar">
    <toolbarbutton id="mouseclick-button" class="mouseclick-class"
                   label="&button.label;" tooltiptext="&tooltip.text;"
                   oncommand = "mouseClick.display();"/>
    </toolbar>
</overlay>
```

**My JS file :**

```
if(mouseClick === undefined) {
  var mouseClick = {
    _x : "not yet clicked" ,
    _y : "not yet clicked"
  };
}

mouseClick.handler = function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX !== undefined ? e.pageX : e.clientX;
  var y = e.pageY !== undefined ? e.pageY : e.clientY;
  /*A TEST ALERT
  alert("(" + x + ", " + y + ")"); // a dummy command for testing
  */
  this._x = x;
  this._y = y;
};

mouseClick.display = function() {
    alert("(" + this._x + ", " + this._y + ")");
};

window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseClick.handler, false);
```

The issue, when I click anywhere in the document, or anywhere in the window except my extension button, the **TEST alert** command alerts the right coordinates.

**However, when I click my button, (which is to trigger the alert command again), 
the first *TEST alert* returns the right coordinates.**

**BUT, the *main alert*, alerts `(not yet clicked, not yet clicked)`.**

Why is my `mouseClick` object getting reset everytime I click my extension's button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is my mouseClick object getting reset everytime I click my extension's button?

It is not reset, *it was never set*.

---

**The problem**

Inside the event handler, `this` refers to `window`, not to `mouseClick`. The handler is not called in the context of the object because you are directly binding it to `window`.

Meaning, inside the function, `this._x = x;` is the same as `window._x = x;`. `myClick._x` is never changed.
Later when you call `mouseClick.display()`, `this` inside that function refers to `mouseClick` and will alert the initial value.

A function is just like any other value. Assigning it to a property of an object does not magically bind it to that object. What `this` refers to is determined when the function is **called**, not when it is created.

[MDN explains `this` very well](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and [quirksmode.org explains it in the light of event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

---

**The solution**

You can explicitly bind the handler to `mouseClick` using [`.bind` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseClick.handler.bind(mouseClick), false);
```

Or alternatively pass a function which in turn calls `mouseClick.handler`:

```
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
    mouseClick.handler(event);
}, false);
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass down the event for the function that calls mouseClick.handler? It's not a problem when you bind the function (since the event listener can then apply the argument), but if you manually handle the call you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @Bubbles: Thanks, forgot about that.